# What kind of lens would eliminate distortion through a cylinder wall?

Tags: optics, lenses

Suppose you are trying to look at an object inside of an acrylic cylinder. What kind of lens could you use on the outside to eliminate the distortion caused by the wall? The image can be inverted.

[image: Object inside a cylinder]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the acrylic tube acts as a diverging lens *to some extent* because the concave side radius (inside diameter) is smaller than the convex side radius. So a cylindrical lens carefully positionned between the observer and the tube should cancel *some* distortion within a limited angle of observation.

Disclaimer: this is highly speculative, but it's better than nothing